# Scope quandary with namespaces, function templates, and static data

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, scope

This scoping problem seems like the type of C++ quandary that Scott Meyers would have addressed in one of his *Effective C++* books.

I have a function, `Analyze`, that does some analysis on a range of data.  The function is called from a few places with different types of iterators, so I have made it a template (and thus implemented it in a header file).  The function depends on a static table of data, `AnalysisTable`, that I don't want to expose to the rest of the code.

My first approach was to make the table a `static const` inside `Analysis`.

```
namespace MyNamespace {

  template <typename InputIterator>
  int Analyze(InputIterator begin, InputIterator end) {
    static const int AnalysisTable[] = { /* data */ };
    ... // implementation uses AnalysisTable
    return result;
  }

}  // namespace MyNamespace
```

It appears that the compiler creates a copy of `AnalysisTable` for each instantiation of `Analyze`, which is wasteful of space (and, to a small degree, time).

So I moved the table outside the function like this:

```
namespace MyNamespace {

  const int AnalysisTable[] = { /* data */ };

  template <typename InputIterator>
  int Analyze(InputIterator begin, InputIterator end) {
    ... // implementation uses AnalysisTable
    return result;
  }

}  // namespace MyNamespace
```

There's only one copy of the table now, but it's exposed to the rest of the code.  I'd rather keep this implementation detail hidden, so I introduced an unnamed namespace:

```
namespace MyNamespace {

  namespace {  // unnamed to hide AnalysisTable
    const int AnalysisTable[] = { /* data */ };
  }  // unnamed namespace

  template <typename InputIterator>
  int Analyze(InputIterator begin, InputIterator end) {
    ... // implementation uses AnalysisTable
    return result;
  }

}  // namespace MyNamespace
```

But now I again have multiple copies of the table, because each compilation unit that includes this header file gets its own.  If `Analyze` weren't a template, I could move all the implementation detail out of the header file.  But it is a template, so I seem stuck.

My next attempt was to put the table in the implementation file and to make an `extern` declaration within `Analyze`.

```
// foo.h ------
namespace MyNamespace {

  template <typename InputIterator>
  int Analyze(InputIterator begin, InputIterator end) {
    extern const int AnalysisTable[];
    ... // implementation uses AnalysisTable
    return result;
  }

}  // namespace MyNamespace

// foo.cpp ------
#include "foo.h"
namespace MyNamespace {
    const int AnalysisTable[] = { /* data */ };
}
```

This looks like it should work, and--indeed--the compiler is satisfied.  The linker, however, complains, "unresolved external symbol `AnalysisTable`."  Drat!  (Can someone explain what I'm missing here?)

The only thing I could think of was to give the inner namespace a name, declare the table in the header, and provide the actual data in an implementation file:

```
// foo.h -----
namespace MyNamespace {

  namespace PrivateStuff {
    extern const int AnalysisTable[];
  }  // unnamed namespace

  template <typename InputIterator>
  int Analyze(InputIterator begin, InputIterator end) {
    ... // implementation uses PrivateStuff::AnalysisTable
    return result;
  }

}  // namespace MyNamespace

// foo.cpp -----
#include "foo.h"
namespace MyNamespace {
  namespace PrivateStuff {
    const int AnalysisTable[] = { /* data */ };
  }
}
```

Once again, I have exactly one instance of `AnalysisTable` (yay!), but other parts of the program can access it (boo!).  The inner namespace makes it a little clearer that they *shouldn't*, but it's still possible.

Is it possible to have one instance of the table and to move the table beyond the reach of everything but `Analyze`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a class with a static member to hold the data if it's really important that nothing but specializations of your function template can access the data.

```
class AnalysisTable
{
    static const int data[];

    template <typename InputIterator>
    friend int Analyze(InputIterator begin, InputIterator end);
};

template <typename InputIterator>
int Analyze(InputIterator begin, InputIterator end)
{
    // ...
    x = AnalysisTable::data[n];
    // ...
}
```